# Type 'S' does not satisfy the constraint 'JSONSchema' in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have set following type in typescript

```
import type {
  APIGatewayProxyEvent,
  APIGatewayProxyResult,
  Handler
} from 'aws-lambda'
import type { FromSchema } from 'json-schema-to-ts'

export type ValidatedAPIGatewayProxyEvent<S> = Omit<APIGatewayProxyEvent,'body'> & { body: FromSchema<S> }
export type ValidatedEventAPIGatewayProxyEvent<S> = Handler<ValidatedAPIGatewayProxyEvent<S>,APIGatewayProxyResult>

export const formatJSONResponse = (
  statusCode: number,
  response: Record<string, unknown>
) => {
  return {
    statusCode: statusCode,
    body: JSON.stringify(response, null, 2)
  }
}
```

When I compile this as follows,it returned following error. I searched root cause but I still have this kind of issue.

```
Type 'S' does not satisfy the constraint 'JSONSchema'.
  Type 'S' is not assignable to type '{ readonly type?: ReadonlyDeep<JSONSchema6TypeName | JSONSchema6TypeName[] | undefined>; readonly const?: ReadonlyDeep<unknown> | undefined; ... 35 more ...; readonly format?: ReadonlyDeep<...>; }'.

8 export type ValidatedAPIGatewayProxyEvent<S> = Omit<APIGatewayProxyEvent,'body'> & { body: FromSchema<S> }
```

If someone has experienced similar issue, will you please let me know. Thanks

Comment: I have no particular experience with 'json-schema-to-ts' but from looking at the code and the the error message, I would assume that `FromSchema<S>` expects a Generic which extends `JSONSchema`. Did you try: `export type ValidatedAPIGatewayProxyEvent<S extends JSONSchema>...`?

Answer (score 2):

It's because your type `ValidatedAPIGatewayProxyEvent<S>` takes a type argument `S`, with no constraints, but then passes it into `FromSchema<S>`, whose first type argument does have a constraint of `S extends JSONSchema`.

https://github.com/ThomasAribart/json-schema-to-ts/blob/0cbb37b85b479148612819600799750070c4c73d/src/index.ts#L48

But there is no guarantee that the `S` type being passed into `ValidatedAPIGatewayProxyEvent`, and therefore the `S` type being passed into `FromSchema`, is assignable to `JSONSchema`.

You probably need to constrain your type argument like so:

```
export type ValidatedAPIGatewayProxyEvent<S extends JSONSchema> = ...
```